# Why is my eventlistener being removed after an element has been dropped using drag / drop API

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, addeventlistener, draggable

Below I have a simplified version of my code where I can click a button to add new elements. These element should all be draggable so they can swap places and they should also have functionality to be deleted when clicking somewhere on them. I have implemented this successfully as you can see by running my snippet ... except for one thing ...

If you try to click on the button area in the middle before swapping it with anything it works just like I want it to.

But if you try to click on it after you have swapped it, it no longer works. Please help me fix this!

```js
const btn_add_element = document.querySelector('.btn_add_element');
const my_draggable_elements = document.querySelector('.my_draggable_elements');

function handleDragStart(e) {
  this.style.opacity = '0.4';
  dragSrcEl = this;
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);
}
function handleDragEnd(e) {
  this.style.opacity = '1';  my_draggable_elements.querySelectorAll('.container').forEach(elm => {
    elm.classList.remove('dragged_over');
  });
}
function handleDragOver(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
function handleDragEnter(e) {
  this.classList.add('dragged_over');
}
function handleDragLeave(e) {
  this.classList.remove('dragged_over');
}
function handleDrop(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  if (dragSrcEl !== this) {
    dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
  }
  return false;
}

function getRandomColor() { return '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16); }

function add_element() {

  // Create Container & Make it draggable
  const new_container = document.createElement('div');
  new_container.classList.add('container');
  new_container.setAttribute('draggable', true);
  new_container.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart);
  new_container.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver);
  new_container.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter);
  new_container.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave);
  new_container.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd);
  new_container.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop);
  
  // Create Content
  const new_content = document.createElement('div');
  new_content.classList.add('content');
  new_content.style.color = getRandomColor();
  new_content.innerText = 'Click to Delete';
  new_content.addEventListener('click', () => {
    new_container.remove();
  });
  new_container.appendChild(new_content);
  my_draggable_elements.appendChild(new_container);
}

btn_add_element.addEventListener('click', () => add_element());

btn_add_element.click();
btn_add_element.click();
btn_add_element.click();
```

```css
.my_draggable_elements {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container {
  padding: 2rem;
  border: 0.1rem solid black;
  cursor: grab;
}
.container.dragged_over {
  border: 0.1rem dashed black;
}
.container > .content {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn_add_element {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='my_draggable_elements'></div>

<button class='btn_add_element'>Add Element</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @anarchist912, I finally got the desired result.

As he stated in his answer, the eventlistener for removing the element gets lost inside the handleDrop function. To fix this we had to manually add the eventlistener back again.

```
this.addEventListener('click', () => {
  this.remove();
});
```

However this was apparently not enough.

I accidentally solved this by writing a remove_element() function for my personal use-case and getting it to work, then realising it was not working here when I tested it in the snippet using the arrow function like above. So here are the changes that made it work:

```
function remove_element(e) {
  e.target.closest('.container').remove();
}

// and inside handleDrop()
dragSrcEl.querySelector('.content').addEventListener('click', remove_element);
this.querySelector('.content').addEventListener('click', remove_element);
```

```js
const btn_add_element = document.querySelector('.btn_add_element');
const my_draggable_elements = document.querySelector('.my_draggable_elements');

function handleDragStart(e) {
  this.style.opacity = '0.4';
  dragSrcEl = this;
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);
}
function handleDragEnd(e) {
  this.style.opacity = '1';  my_draggable_elements.querySelectorAll('.container').forEach(elm => {
    elm.classList.remove('dragged_over');
  });
}
function handleDragOver(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
function handleDragEnter(e) {
  this.classList.add('dragged_over');
}
function handleDragLeave(e) {
  this.classList.remove('dragged_over');
}
function handleDrop(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  if (dragSrcEl !== this) {
    dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    dragSrcEl.querySelector('.content').addEventListener('click', remove_element);
    this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    this.querySelector('.content').addEventListener('click', remove_element);
  }
  return false;
}

function getRandomColor() { return '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16); }

function remove_element(e) {
  e.target.closest('.container').remove();
}

function add_element() {

  // Create Container & Make it draggable
  const new_container = document.createElement('div');
  new_container.classList.add('container');
  new_container.setAttribute('draggable', true);
  new_container.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart);
  new_container.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver);
  new_container.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter);
  new_container.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave);
  new_container.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd);
  new_container.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop);
  
  // Create Content
  const new_content = document.createElement('div');
  new_content.classList.add('content');
  new_content.style.color = getRandomColor();
  new_content.innerText = 'Click to Delete';
  new_content.addEventListener('click', remove_element);
  new_container.appendChild(new_content);
  my_draggable_elements.appendChild(new_container);
}

btn_add_element.addEventListener('click', () => add_element());

btn_add_element.click();
btn_add_element.click();
btn_add_element.click();
```

```css
.my_draggable_elements {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container {
  padding: 2rem;
  border: 0.1rem solid black;
  cursor: grab;
}
.container.dragged_over {
  border: 0.1rem dashed black;
}
.container > .content {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn_add_element {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='my_draggable_elements'></div>

<button class='btn_add_element'>Add Element</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In `handleDrop()` the element get's transfered from `event.dataTransfer.getData('text/html')` to the innerHTML of the element it is being dropped on. In that, the eventListener is lost. You have to add it again, as demonstrated in the modified snippet below.

```js
const btn_add_element = document.querySelector('.btn_add_element');
const my_draggable_elements = document.querySelector('.my_draggable_elements');

function handleDragStart(e) {
  this.style.opacity = '0.4';
  dragSrcEl = this;
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);
}
function handleDragEnd(e) {
  this.style.opacity = '1';  my_draggable_elements.querySelectorAll('.container').forEach(elm => {
    elm.classList.remove('dragged_over');
  });
}
function handleDragOver(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
function handleDragEnter(e) {
  this.classList.add('dragged_over');
}
function handleDragLeave(e) {
  this.classList.remove('dragged_over');
}
function handleDrop(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  if (dragSrcEl !== this) {
    dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    console.log(this.innerHTML);
    this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    this.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.remove();
    });
  }
  return false;
}

function getRandomColor() { return '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16); }

function add_element() {

  // Create Container & Make it draggable
  const new_container = document.createElement('div');
  new_container.classList.add('container');
  new_container.setAttribute('draggable', true);
  new_container.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart);
  new_container.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver);
  new_container.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter);
  new_container.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave);
  new_container.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd);
  new_container.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop);
  
  // Create Content
  const new_content = document.createElement('div');
  new_content.classList.add('content');
  new_content.style.color = getRandomColor();
  new_content.innerText = 'Click to Delete';
  new_content.addEventListener('click', () => {
    new_container.remove();
  });
  new_container.appendChild(new_content);
  my_draggable_elements.appendChild(new_container);
}

btn_add_element.addEventListener('click', () => add_element());

btn_add_element.click();
btn_add_element.click();
btn_add_element.click();
```

```css
.my_draggable_elements {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container {
  padding: 2rem;
  border: 0.1rem solid black;
  cursor: grab;
}
.container.dragged_over {
  border: 0.1rem dashed black;
}
.container > .content {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn_add_element {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='my_draggable_elements'></div>

<button class='btn_add_element'>Add Element</button>
```

Comment: After I modified this to also add the eventlistener to the dragSrcEl in the drop function aswel I got it to work, thank you!

Comment: Yeah, but try to drag around multiple times. Something doesn't work yet. At some point one element will delete itself and another element, while a third element doesn't have the eventListener any more.

Comment: I figured it out. The problem is that we were adding the eventlistener to the container element itself in the handleDrop function whereas it is supposed to be attached to the content element instead. After changing the code to this.querySelector('.content').addEventListener( ... ) I got it to work

Comment: I realised there was yet another missing piece to make it work, but finally now, it should work fully. I made an answer with all my modifications. Thank you for your help.